# How to import/upload multiple json files to Azure Devops Pipeline Builds?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

The following script tries to import multiple json files to Azure DevOps Pipeline builds.

```
$JsonNames = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\*.json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

ForEach ($JN in $JsonNames)

{

$token = "PAT token"

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{Project}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0-preview.2"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON= Get-Content "C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\$($JN).json"


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON


}
```

However I receive the following error message.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The request specifies project ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx but the supplied pipeline specifies project ID 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.RouteIdConflictException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"RouteIdConflictException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At line:17 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "B ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

As mentioned on the error message, I opened one JSON file on Notepad++ and updated the project ID. I tried to run it again but receive the following message.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"To get sources from a different team project, on the Options tab you must set the build job authorization 
scope to ‘Project collection’ and ensure that the 'Limit job authorization scope to current project' pipeline setting is 
disabled.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.InvalidDefinitionException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"InvalidDefinitionException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At line:17 char:13
+ $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "B ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Then I made minor changes on the script.

```
$Json = Get-ChildItem C:\users\username\desktop\test\*.json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
ForEach ($J in $Json)

{
$token = "PAT token"
$header = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' +[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))}
$JN = Get-Content "C:\users\username\desktop\test\$($J)"
$body = $JN | ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -uri 'https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0' -Body '$body' -Headers '$header' -ContentType 'application/json'

}
```

I received the following message. Could someone please help me? I have tried multiple things and I am not still not able to get this resolved.

```
Invoke-RestMethod : Cannot bind parameter 'Headers'. Cannot convert the "$header" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.IDictionary". At line:10 char:146

... h/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0' -Headers '$header' -Conten ...
                                                    ~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-RestMethod], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: @Kevin Lu-MSFT, I am sorry for the late response. Thank you your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the sample and reproduce the same issues. It seems that you are create the build pipeline in another project.

To solve this issue, you need to change the following settings:

In build json file, you need to change the **projectID** and the **QueueID**.

You could get the QueueID in **Project Settings -> Agent Pools -> Target Pool**.

[image]

Json file sample: Change Queueid

```
{"href":"https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/_apis/build/Queues/337"}},"id":337,"name":"Azure Pipelines","url":"https://dev.azure.com/{Org}/_apis/build/Queues/337","pool":{"id":9,"name":"Azure Pipelines","isHosted":true}},
```

In the target Project, you need to navigate to **Project Settings -> Settings** . Then you could disable the **Limit job authorization scope to current project for non-release pipeline** option.

[image]

**Note:** If you cannot change this setting in Project Settings, you need to turn off the corresponding option in **Organization Settings -> Settings**.

Here is my script sample:

```
$JsonNames = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\path\Downloads\*.json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

ForEach ($JN in $JsonNames)

{

$token = "PAT"

$url = "https://dev.azure.com/{organizationName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$JSON= Get-Content "C:\Users\<UserName>\Desktop\$($JN).json"

echo $JSON


$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -ContentType application/json -body $JSON


}
```

**Note:** You need to change the API Version **api-version=6.0-preview.2** to **api-version=6.0**. The **api-version=6.0-preview.2** is not the version in [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Comment: thank you for your help. Yes I have an existing project and I am trying to create a build on another project. I am saving builds from existing project to desktop and then trying to import the build from desktop to new project using PowerShell. I understand there is a way of cloning builds between projects but I need to follow this step where I have to save the build on desktop. There are several builds that I need to import. Do you know if there is a way to just import them to new project from desktop without changing the queue id or project id?

Comment: Hi @albbla91. Since you are using the classic UI pipeline, you can only export the definition as json file. Then you could generate the same pipeline in another project. In this case, there is no method to  import them to new project from desktop without changing the queue id or project id.  I could understand your requirement. But there is no method could achieve this goal. You could check if the sample in the answer could work. Thanks for your understanding.